# installing library event package

Tags: package-management, libraries

All resources i have come across say that this should work:

apt-get install libevent-dev

But this fails event even when I have super user privileges.

Does anyone know of a repository for this package?

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

thanks in advance

Error output:

Reading package lists...Done

Building dependency tree...Done

Reading state information...Done

E: Unable to locate package libevent-dev

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of a failed attempt. The package is in the 'main' pocket of the Ubuntu repositories for all supported releases of Ubuntu - every install of Ubuntu already has that source included.

Comment: ok i have done so, it says it is unable to locate it, is this likely to be an issue caused by what is in my /etc/apt/sources.list file?

Comment: That's one line, not complete output. Seems likely that you have bonkered sources. Please edit your question to show the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: I KNOW but this is the output relevant to the issue the rest is not of any concern

Comment: ok there it is, that is the full output

Comment: ah well one of the first things i did was update from the four main repositories, and with the exception of the US archive they have all installed their packages without any problem

Comment: cant you just show me what my output of sudo apt update *should* look like, and i can work with that?

Comment: ok well the point is the mirrors i do have are not directly relevant to the successful installation of this package that is in the main repositories as you said so, i feel as if this wont help at all

Comment: It's pretty simple: The package you want is definitely in '-main'. If apt cannot locate the package, then your local package database is not being populated from your chosen mirror (that's what `apt update` does). Hence the request for a complete `apt update` output - it will tell us if you have a source problem, or any of several types of network problem.

Comment: A proper apt update looks like this: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/8g45Vxgs3C/

Comment: was resolved by adding the content missing in the sources.list file, at some point I must have wiped it accidentally

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036408/what-is-the-default-content-of-etc-apt-sources-list-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic

Answer (score 1):

First Update the System with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try to install libevent-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: Sorry mate same issue when I update prior to installation unfortunately

Comment: Try with **sudo apt-get upgrade**. It will replace the Older version packages.

Comment: ok thanks the output from this says that the package gdb was held back and not upgraded. Could this be relevant?

Comment: Might be, Package gdb is GNU debugger package update this and Try for the libevent-dev.

Comment: I corrected the problem comparing the content of my sources.list file to that list in questions like this thanks anyway though

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036408/what-is-the-default-content-of-etc-apt-sources-list-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic